# How to show that a operator is (not) self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In order to prove that an operator is self-adjoint or not, what should I do?

> For example, how can I show that the following operator is self-adjoint?
>   $K: C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ with 
>   $$[Kf](x)=\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)dy \qquad \text{where}\qquad 
> k(x,y):= (1 + i) x + (1 - i) y.$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please explain more?

Comment: K : C[a; b] ----->C[a; b]

Comment: exactly, I got what do you mean. But I made a mistake, k is self adjoint. I am going to edit it.

Comment: Sorry, I should write the question with all details. I will edit it now.

Comment: Are you considering $C[0,1]$ with an inner product? $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f \bar g$?

Comment: yes, I am not sure what exactly I should do.

Comment: @Shalaleh I tried to improve a bit your edit. Please check that it is correct (and also you might be interested to see how I rewrote your Mathjax. Anyway thanks for the effort of trying to improve the format :).

Comment: Thnak you so much!

Comment: If you want to ask another question write a new post, don't overload this one. Such is the rule of this site: one post, one question.

Comment: Okay, but the title is the same. I will try to ask it in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, of adjoints
\begin{equation}
\langle Kf, g \rangle = \langle f, K^* g \rangle,
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where we consider $C[0,1]$ as a subspace of $L^2[0,1]$ with the inner product $\langle u, v \rangle = \int_0^1 u \bar v$. We know how to compute $Kf$, so we plug this into $(1)$ and deduce what the function $K^*g$ must be, hence what $K^*$ must be. Here it goes.
\begin{align*}
\langle Kf, g \rangle &= \int_0^1 [Kf](x) \bar g(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y) \, dy \right) \bar g(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y) \bar g(x) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(y) \overline{k(y,x) g(x)} \, dy \, dx && k(x,y) = \bar k(y,x) \\
&= \int_0^1 f(y)  \overline{ \left(\int_0^1 k(y,x) g(x) \, dx \right)} \, dy &&\mbox{Fubini's theorem; $\int \bar u = \overline{\int u}$} \\
&= \langle f, K^* g \rangle \\
\implies [K^*g](y) &= \int_0^1 k(y,x) g(x) \, dx.
\end{align*}
Now if we swap the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the last equation, we have $[K^*g](x) = \int_0^1 k(x,y) g(y) \, dy = [Kg](x)$. This holds for arbitrary $g$, so $K^* = K$, and $K$ is self adjoint.

Comment: It is equal to $[Kg](y)$ though? Since variable names might be confusing: $[Kg](x)=\int k(x,y)g(y)dx \implies [Kg](y)\int k(y,z) g(z)dz$ which is your expression for $[K^* g](y)$.

Comment: My mistake, you are right! I'll edit the conclusion!

Answer (score 1):

An operator $A$ on a star algebra is self adjoint iff $A^*=A$.

Here $(K^*f)(x) =\int_0^1 \bar{k}(y,x)f(y)dy$ where $\bar{k}(y,x)$ is to be the complex conjugate of $k(y,x)$. Now since $k(x,y)=(1+i)x+(1-i)y=\bar{k}(y,x)$ you have:

$$(K^*f)(x)=\int_0^1 \bar{k}(y,x)f(y)dy=\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)dy = (Kf)(x)$$

for all $f$ in your vector space. Since the linear maps are defined by their action on the vector space this implies $K^*=K$ and $K$ is self adjoint.

In order to see why $K^*$ takes the specific form, note that $K$ is a bounded operator on the Hilbert space $L^2([0,1])$, so $K^*$ exists and for all $f,g$ in the space:

$$(g,Kf)=\int \bar{g}(x) k(x,y)f(y)dx dy=\int \overline{\bar k(x,y)g(x)}\,f(y)dx dy \overset{!}{=} (K^*g,f)=\int (\overline{K^*g})(y)f(y)dy$$

Since this holds for all $f$ in the Hilbert space it implies $(K^*g)(y)=\int\bar k(x,y)g(x)dx$ for all $g$.

Comment: Is there any book which has questions like the above question to practice functional analysis more? with the solutions?

Comment: I don't know any specific resources, sorry. The only functional analysis book I ever read were chapters in Bratteli and Robinson on C* Algebras, which might not be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have another question related to adjoint operator, if you are interested to answer, I will appreciate you.(adjoint operator with matrix)

Comment: why $k(x,y) =\bar k(y,x)$ ? is it always correct, for example about $k(x,y)= (1+i)x +(2-i)y$ is it correct?

Comment: It is correct in this case, not in general (you have misstyped $k$ in the comment). You have $k(x,y) = (1+i)x + (1-i)y$, complex conjugating the entire thing gives you $\bar k (x,y) = (1-i)x +(1+i)y$ since $x, y$ are real. But this is the same number as $k(y,x)$ for any $x,y$.

Comment: No, it is not miss typing, in the proof you used this fact that $k(x,y)=\bar k(y,x)$, if it is not correct in general, why you are using it in the proof?

Comment: When I say general, I mean it is not true for arbitrary functions $k: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$. The typo in your comment is $k(x,y)=(1+i)x+({\bf{2}}-i)y$. The relation $\bar k(x,y)=k(y,x)$ is true for _the specific function k_ that you have given, not for _any_ function.

Comment: yes, I just wanted to show in a example that it is not correct in general, so, if we want find adjoint operator in general, what should we do?

Comment: The adjoint is defined over the scalar product, if for all vectors $v,w$ in the space: $<v,Lw>$ can be written as $<L^*v,w>$ for an operator $L^*$, then $L^*$ is the adjoint of $L$. The strategy to construct it is to look at the expression $<v,Lw>$ in general and try to bring the $L$ over to the other side via some modifications to get $L^*$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. But I mean if we want to find adjoint operator in this question in general, what is neccessary to do? because as you said it is not correct to any arbitrary functions. Assume we want to find adjoint operator for any arbitrary function, not just for those we have $k(x,y)=\bar k(y,x)$.

Comment: In this case we verify explicitly that $k(x,y) = \bar k(y,x)$ holds. For each $x,y$ you have on the left and on the right a number. Namely $\bar k(x,y) = \overline{(1+i)x+(1-i)y}=(1-i)x+(1+i)y=(1+i)y+(1-i)x$ While $k(y,x)=(1+i)y+(1-i)x$. The expressions are the same.

Comment: $$(g,Kf)=\int \bar{g}(x) k(x,y)f(y)dx dy=\int \overline{\bar k(x,y)g(x)}\,f(y)dx dy $$ in the proof we should use general theorems, yes? so if $k(x,y)=\bar k(y,x)$ is not correct in general, why are you using in your proof?

Comment: There you would see that if $K$ acts on $f$ in the way of $(Kf)(x)=\int k(x,y)f(y)dy$ then $(K^*f)(x)=\int \bar k (y,x) f(y) dy$.